# How do I breed a Copper dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I heard the May 25th update added a Copper Dragon. Which dragons do I need to breed to get one and how long do they take to breed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to breed a Copper Dragon:
The [Dragonvale Wiki page](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Copper_Dragon) explains:

> The Copper Dragon can be bred by selecting a metal dragon to mate with a lightning dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

You don't need any hybrid dragons, just **Metal and Lightning** dragons.

You'll know you have a Copper Dragon when you get a breeding/egg time of **20 hours**. Alternately you may get a Magnetic Dragon with a breeding/egg time of 4 hours.

Copper Dragon eggs look like this:

[image]

And the baby will look like this:

[image]

<sub><sup>All images from [Dragonvale Wiki: Copper Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Copper_Dragon)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here are combinations that have all have the fastest "failure rate." Meaning the average time wasted if you don't successfully breed a copper dragon is only 2.45 hours.

Breeding Combination 1: 
CactusDragon + CopperDragon
Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 2: 
CactusDragon + MagneticDragon
Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 3: 
CactusDragon + MetalDragon
Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 4: 
CopperDragon + PlantDragon
Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 5: 
MagneticDragon + PlantDragon
Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Calculations done at http://dvcalc.pf-control.de/

Answer (score 0):

I got the copper dragon by using (scorch) & (metal) first try. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the copper using lightning and metal