# How to breed a Copper dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I breed a Copper dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70370/how-do-i-breed-a-copper-dragon)

How do you breed a Copper Dragon on DragonVale? I have spent almost 250 gems trying the Lightning/Metal combo but all I get is Magnetic dragons. If anyone has any other successful combos please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, Kris, but this appears to **already been asked and possibly answered.** _Remember, when you are about to ask a question, make sure someone already hasn't asked and maybe even answered this question._ Sadly I must **not up-vote vote this question.** But try again, and **Happy Arqading!**

Answer (score 1):

Here are combinations that have all have the fastest "failure rate." Meaning the average time wasted if you don't successfully breed a copper dragon is only 2.45 hours.

Breeding Combination 1: CactusDragon + CopperDragon Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 2: CactusDragon + MagneticDragon Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 3: CactusDragon + MetalDragon Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 4: CopperDragon + PlantDragon Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Breeding Combination 5: MagneticDragon + PlantDragon Failure Average: 2.25 hrs

Calculations done at http://dvcalc.pf-control.de/

Comment: Your answer is great, but turns out this was a duplicate question. Unfortunately, this question was already asked and possibly answered! But since it was such a great answer, I'll give you a **+1!**